# Retrieve values from array

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, datatables

I have the following code and my goal is to retrieve a list of IDs from the value of input elements based on rows I have selected. But my array contains the entire input element. How do I retrieve only the values?

```
var table = $('#tbl').DataTable();

$('#tbl tbody').on('click', 'tr', function() {
  $(this).toggleClass('selected');
});

$('#button').click(function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();

  var selectedRows = $.map(table.rows('.selected').data(), function(item) {
    return item[0]
  });

  console.log(selectedRows)

  alert(table.rows('.selected').data().length + ' row(s) selected');
```

Below is the result for `selectedRows`, but I want to retrieve only values

```
0:'<input type="hidden" value="1" name="RowId" id="RowId" class=" RowIdClass">'
1:'<input type="hidden" value="2" name="RowId" id="RowId" class=" RowIdClass">'
2:'<input type="hidden" value="3" name="RowId" id="RowId" class=" RowIdClass">'
3:'<input type="hidden" value="4" name="RowId" id="RowId" class=" RowIdClass">'
4:'<input type="hidden" value="5" name="RowId" id="RowId" class=" RowIdClass">'
```

Comment: Hi, instead of `item[0]` can you try `$(item[0]).val()` ?

Comment: Seems to me, you're mixing DOM and datatables data.  The DOM (`<table>` `<tr>` etc) are *representations* of the *current* page of actual data.   If you want to add `selected` to the DOM, then read `.selected` from the DOM - and thus the hidden input directly from the DOM: `$(".selected").find("input").map((i, e) => $(e).val())`

Comment: You don't need to use (and shouldn't use) hidden DOM inputs to add data to datatables.  Instead of `<td><input type='hidden' value='1'>Column 1</td>` do `<td style='display:none;'>1</td><td>Column 1</td>` (and corresponding change to thead).  Then your code works exactly as you expected:  https://jsfiddle.net/y7sjcwop/

Comment: @freedomn-m - Your solutions works for me as well, Thank you!